# Want to change 2 or more attributes of a css in a single line of jquery code,How could I do that?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

Can I use some jquery where I can change the css attributes in a single line , more like

```
 $("#box").css("height":"40px",
                "width":"40px"
               );
```

instead of 2 lines of code like this?

```
$("#box").css("height","40px");
$("#box").css("width","40px");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   $('#box').css({
    "height": "40px",
    "width": "40px"
  });
```

or you can try

```
$("#box").css("height","40px").css("width","40px");
```

Comment: $("#h1").css({height: "40px",
                          width: "40px"});
           got it, a little change though, just the values needed inverted commas, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can pass multiple css properties in an object to jQuery's [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method like this:

```
.css({"propertyname":"value","propertyname":"value",...});
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('#change').on('click', function(e) {
    $("#box").css(
      {
        "height": "40px", // <----- add css property here
        "width": "40px" // <----- add another css property here
      }               
    );
  });
})
```

```css
#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box"></div>
<br>
<button id="change">Change CSS</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way, use `.addClass()` method in jquery for the element id `#box`

```
$("#box").addClass("newclass");
```

in the css

```
.newclass {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just by passing an object you can change any amount of CSS attributes

```
$("#box").css({
    "height":"40px",
    "width":"40px"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $("#box").css({
      "height":"40px",
      "width":"40px"
  });
```